# How to debug a Heroku request timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout

How would I find out what is causing h12 timeout errors on heroku?

It happens randomly on different pages/controllers.

This is the error that I get from the logs

```
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2013-08-15T13:08:54.718157+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signup" for 105.226.239.198 at 2013-08-15 13:08:54 +0000
2013-08-15T13:08:54.744390+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered communal/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
2013-08-15T13:09:24.714225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/signup host=www.goodwordlabs.com fwd="105.226.239.198" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-08-15T13:09:25.518168+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-08-15T13:09:25.517428 #2] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:5 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
2013-08-15T13:09:25.554402+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-08-15T13:09:25.554166 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
2013-08-15T13:09:25.980010+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-15T13:09:25.979551 #26]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2013-08-15T13:08:51.088169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/clients/client1-03dfd2afecf092e15b9e3350d04acdc6.png host=www.goodwordlabs.com fwd="105.226.239.198" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you should proceed

1. Install a application monitoring solution [newrelic](http://newrelic.com). It would give you list of URL that are timing out. New relic is paid, but there is free version of new relic too.
2. Now, try to isolate & reproduce timeout error. because if you can't reproduce it. you can't fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I will add newrelic back to the app

Answer (score 0):

you can try sending request to site(www.goodwordlabs.com) from heroku console. Run heroku console with this
`heroku run rails console`

or try sending request with same parameters from Curl of terminal

Comment: It just seems to happen randomly on different pages at different times.