# Why is the Django app I moved to Heroku crashing inexplicably?

Tags: django, heroku

I have a locally running Django App which I'm trying to move into Heroku. I'm following and adapting [**these**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) instructions to do so. However, when I push my code to Heroku, the app is unavailable via Web Browser. When I tail the logs, I see many lines such as these:

```
2014-09-25T17:02:21.927991+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-25 17:02:21 [2] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)
2014-09-25T17:02:23.050632+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-25 17:02:23 [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2014-09-25T17:02:54.021864+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-25 17:02:54 [2] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)
2014-09-25T17:02:55.039070+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-25 17:02:55 [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2014-09-25T17:03:26.061225+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-25 17:03:26 [2] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12)
2014-09-25T17:03:27.081593+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-25 17:03:27 [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
```

Why am I getting this indecipherable error and how can I fix it? 
What other things should I look at to troubleshoot this?

Here is the contents of my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn MyProject.wsgi --log-file -
```

**EDIT:** FYI: When I run this same app locally using foreman start, it works.

Comment: Can you share the entire log? (or, if it's too big, the last 100-200 lines?)

Comment: Thanks Yuvi. Here is the most logs I can share: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/e8ed8e1b99f335c2389b.

Comment: FYI: When I run this same app locally using foreman start, it works.

Comment: I see one error there that's going to be a bit tough to debug - `reqest timeout`. Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253632/how-to-debug-a-heroku-request-timeout-error) on a similar question, and try to figure out why you're getting that one (reading the name, I'm assuming it means the request takes too long. Try figuring out what part of the code might get stuck or get in some infinite loop... maybe you're not connecting correctly to the db? Is it limited to only some of the views - then what's different about those requests... etc. etc.)